# How to view the front-end of a Wordpress website when you have downloaded the code?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting, wordpress-shortcode

I appreciate that this is a basic question, but I am learning web development.

I have downloaded the code for a WordPress website. How do I now use this code so I can view the front-end of the website and continue to have admin access of the Wordpress website.

Is it just a matter of going with a hosting provider and add the code files on their platform?

I am seeking assistance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can open downloaded pages on your "localhost" to basically host it on your local machine and view it locally. You can make many different choices in running Websites locally, e.g. you could use XAMPP or flywheel for Wordpress.
I would suggest you to go through a tutorial like [this one](https://wpmet.com/install-wordpress-on-localhost/) and follow the steps there, as it would take a very long time to explain all of the steps.